# Need a method for searching all of C drive for a directory in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, exception, directory

I need to find a folder called "GameData", in the filesystem, its normally stored in Program Files, but if it is not, i would like to be able to find it, wherever it is in the C drive.

Currently, i'm using:

```
IEnumerable<string> list = Directory.GetDirectories(root, "GameData", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException` which is expected, as it is trying to navigate through protected directories.

Is there perhaps something i can add to this to stop it from attempting to access any protected directories? Will a `try/catch` block allow the search to continue after the exception?

**EDIT**

Note: I'm not looking for a specific file, just the folder called GameData, so that i can use that location as an output for .zip extraction, or to read the names of the folders within.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way of finding that folder? Keep in mind there might be more than one `GameData` directories in the entire filesystem. And searching the entire filesystem may take a while... Are you looking for a folder within an installed application?

Comment: I have a folder called "GameData" where I keep all my photos of my pet fish and a few key important documents... Hope your software not going to trash it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a recursive method instead of `AllDirectories`. Then you could skip directories which cause an exception.

[MSDN: Iterate Through a Directory Tree (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx)

"The weakness in using `SearchOption.AllDirectories`  is that if any one of the subdirectories under the specified root causes a `DirectoryNotFoundException` or `UnauthorizedAccessException`, the whole method fails and returns no directories. The same is true when you use the `GetFiles` method. If you have to handle these exceptions on specific subfolders, you must manually walk the directory tree"

```
static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

    // First, process all the files directly under this folder 
    try
    {
        files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
    }
    // This is thrown if even one of the files requires permissions greater 
    // than the application provides. 
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        // This code just writes out the message and continues to recurse. 
        // You may decide to do something different here. For example, you 
        // can try to elevate your privileges and access the file again.
        log.Add(e.Message);
    }

    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            // In this example, we only access the existing FileInfo object. If we 
            // want to open, delete or modify the file, then 
            // a try-catch block is required here to handle the case 
            // where the file has been deleted since the call to TraverseTree().
            Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
        }

        // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
        subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
        {
            // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
            WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check **[How to recursively search directories by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974)**:

The `GetDirectories` and `GetFiles` methods of the Directory object are all that you need to recursively search for files that match the search string. The following method is used to perform the recursion:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir) 
{
    try 
    {
       foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
       {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
        {
           lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
        }
        DirSearch(d);
       }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The files are of no concern to me, so would i just remove the innermost for loop and use something like `Directory.GetDirecotries(d, "GameData");` instead?

Comment: @sh3rifme:- You can give it a try!

Comment: So it works when i use it on my desktop, but fails if i try using on just C:/ Is there a reason for that?