# Exclude directories from file search in C#

Tags: c#

I try to search a file system using

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories
```

Let's say i want to search the whole C:\ in Windows, but i want to exclude some pathes (e.g. C:\asdf, C:\lorem\ipsum) or folder names (e.g. folder1, folder2, ...). I want to create a statement that filters out pathes and folders from a string list. That means:

```
List<string> exclude = new List<string>{@"C:\asdf", @"C:\lorem\ipsum", "folder2"};
```

How can i exclude these pathes and folder names from the above directory search?

Comment: If you search the whole C drive i recommend to not use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` but a custom method that walks through the directory hierarchy. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22223799/284240). Then skip/exclude paths which are contained in `exclude`.

Comment: Is `"folder2"` a partial directory name?

Comment: `var result = new DirectoryInfo("your path").EnumerateDirectories().Where(d => !exclude.Contains(d.Name));`

Comment: @MarkusDeibel It is just a folder somewhere in a path

Comment: Then @SeM's approach is unfortunately not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> exclude = new List<string> { @"C:\asdf", @"C:\lorem\ipsum", "folder2" };

Func<string, string, bool> containsCaseInsensitivePredicate = (s, p) => s.IndexOf(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;

Func<string, bool> notInExcludeListPredicate = (s) => !exclude.Any(ex => containsCaseInsensitivePredicate(ex, s));

IEnumerable<string> directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\").Where(notInExcludeListPredicate);
```